# Redux reducer isn't returning the updated state to UI

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer case, and this case is supposed to add a comment, and update the UI with the new comment,

Pretty much you add a comment, and it will show under the rest of comments once you do, the logic is not returning the new state for some reason.

What could be the cause of this ? And to be honest im unsure of what im doing, im fairly new when it comes to reducer normalizer state updates.

Only on refresh i see the new comment.

```
const initialState = {
  allIds:[],
  byId:{},
};

const allIds = (state = initialState.allIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case  FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return action.images.reduce((nextState, image) => {
        if (nextState.indexOf(image.id) === -1) {
          nextState.push(image.id);
        }
        return nextState;
      }, [...state]);
      case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action.data)
        return [action.data.id, ...state];

      case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action)
        return [action.data.id, ...state];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
const image = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
      return [...state.comments, action.data, ...state.comments]

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const byId = (state = initialState.byId, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
      return action.images.reduce((nextState, image) => {
        nextState[image.id] = image;

        return nextState;
      }, {...state});
    case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action.data) // renders new commnent
      return {
        ...state,
        ...state.comments,
        [action.data.id]: action.data,

      }
    case UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.data.id]: action.data,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you separating key/value pairs of your state into separate variables instead of having a single state within one reducer?

Comment: Hey @ChristopherNgo long time no see, and its because of state normalization. converting it into a normalized structure has been challenging. here is my old code before normaliztion, see how NON flat the reducer code is https://github.com/EliHood/ReactExpressPhotoShareApp/blob/master/client/src/reducers/imageReducer.js, this is why im trying to make it easy to access nested data.

Comment: im following from this guys code https://github.com/hibiken/hackafy/blob/master/src/reducers/posts.js

Comment: Yeah haha! Hope you're doing well. This task looks like a nightmares @___@

Comment: i knowwwwwwwww, but i need to have a way to easily access deeply nested objects, and stuff. I'm debugging around until the solution comes to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure because I don't see the shape of your `byId` object, but I think the problem might be here:

```
case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state, // here you are spreading the whole state object
    // and here you are spreading state.comments at the same level, NOT nested:
    ...state.comments,
    // Again same thing here, not nested:
    [action.data.id]: action.data,
  }
```

Instead you should be doing something like this, more info [in the Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data):

```
case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    comments: {
      ...state.comments,
      [action.data.id]: action.data
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you could use [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) to simplify your reducers, I'm using it and I'm loving it. It feels a little bit weird because you can use mutation methods to modify its `draft` but it is great if you want to have simpler reducers. Your code with Immer would be something much more simpler:

```
case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
  draft.comments[action.data.id]: action.data,
  return;
```

With Immer you just have to modifiy (or mutate) the `draft` object, if the value you are assigning to is different from the one you have in state, it will generate a new object for you, otherwise it will return state.

Hope it helps.

Comment: about to give this a shot, will let you know how it went.

Comment: `return {
    ...state,
    state.comments: {
      ...state.comments,
      [action.data.id]: action.data
    }` seems like a syntax error

Comment: Think you are missing a `}`

Comment: i copy pasted your code and i get the syntax error, i don't think you can do state.comments:{}

Comment: you can do state:{} but not state.comments:{} any work around for this ?

Comment: Would you please share the shape of your store so I can see it?

Comment: its just a syntax error, their is something off with the way its written in the case. This has nothing to do with the functionality just yet.

Comment: it wont let you do state.comments:{} it throws a syntax error when you do it like that.

Comment: oh, yes I see it, updating the example above. It is `comments: ... ` instead of `state.comments: ...`

Comment: question, considering the object in the picture above, if comments was spelled as  comet, will i call it in reducer case as `..state, comet:{...state.comet, blah, blah}` I'm trying to understand how reducer know where to access the nested data.

Comment: Exactly, but this is a ES6 thing, this is how the spread operator works , nothing to do with reducers themselves

Comment: i see, thanks for the assistance i understand a little bit better, if all fails, im switching over to immer.

Comment: one more thing :( ... this doesn't seem to update to ui, could it be the shape of the action.data property ?. action.data is an array with the respective comment data, like id, comment body, user id, etc.

Comment: so im thinking this would be the way to update the state apporiately      `comments: [
            ...state.comments,
            {
              [action.data]: action.data
            }

          ]
        }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200574/discussion-between-oriol-grau-and-barnowl).